# Haskell Access Tuple Data Inside List Comprehension

Tags: haskell, types, tuples

I have defined a custom type as follows:

```
-- Atom reference number, x coordinate, y coordinate, z coordinate, element symbol, 
--      atom name, residue sequence number, amino acid abbreviation
type Atom = (Int, Double, Double, Double, Word8, ByteString, Int, ByteString)
```

I would like to gather all of the atoms with a certain residue sequence number nm.

This would be nice:

```
[x | x <- p, d == nm]
where
    (_, _, _, _, _, _, d, _) = x
```

where p is a list of atoms.

However, this does not work because I can not access the variable x outside of the list comprehension, nor can I think of  a way to access a specific tuple value from inside the list comprehension.

Is there a tuple method I am missing, or should I be using a different data structure?

I know I could write a recursive function that unpacks and checks every tuple in the list p, but I am actually trying to use this nested inside an already recursive function, so I would rather not need to introduce that complexity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
[x | (_, _, _, _, _, _, d, _) <- p, d == nm]
```

However, you should *really* define your own data type here. A three-element tuple is suspicious; an eight-element tuple is very bad news indeed. Tuples are difficult to work with and less type-safe than data types (if you represent two different kinds of data with two tuples with the same element types, they can be used interchangeably). Here's how I'd write `Atom` as a record:

```
data Point3D = Point3D Double Double Double

data Atom = Atom
  { atomRef :: Int
  , atomPos :: Point3D
  , atomSymbol :: Word8
  , atomName :: ByteString
  , atomSeqNum :: Int
  , atomAcidAbbrev :: ByteString
  } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

(The "atom" prefix is to avoid clashing with the names of fields in other records.)

You can then write the list comprehension as follows:

```
[x | x <- p, atomSeqNum x == nm]
```

As a bonus, your definition of `Atom` becomes self-documenting, and you reap the benefits of increased type safety. Here's how you'd create an `Atom` using this definition:

```
myAtom = Atom
  { atomRef = ...
  , atomPos = ...
  , ... etc. ...
  }
```

By the way, it's probably a good idea to make some of the fields of these types strict, which can be done by putting an exclamation mark before the type of the field; this helps avoid *space leaks* from unevaluated thunks building up. For instance, since it doesn't make much sense to evaluate a `Point3D` without also evaluating all its components, I would instead define `Point3D` as:

```
data Point3D = Point3D !Double !Double !Double
```

It would probably be a good idea to make all the fields of `Atom` strict too, although perhaps not all of them; for example, the `ByteString` fields should be left non-strict if they're generated by the program, not always accessed and possibly large. On the other hand, if their values are read from a file, then they should probably be made strict.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect.  Thank you.  The world looks so much brighter, now.

Comment: Is an "eight-element tuple very bad news indeed" simply because it is hard to work with, or are tuples also hard on performance?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to recommend making some of the fields strict, since you mentioned aiming for performance in your previous question; along with forgetting `-O2`, insufficient strictness is one of the most common Haskell performance problems. :)

Comment: Tuples are difficult to work with and less type-safe than data types (if you represent two different kinds of data with two tuples with the same element types, they can be used interchangeably). The performance should be basically the same as a data type, though, with the important caveat that you can't make tuple fields strict.

Answer (score 4):

You should *definitely* use a different structure. Instead of using a tuple, take a look at [records](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

```
data Atom = Atom { reference :: Int
                 , position :: (Double, Double, Double)
                 , symbol :: Word8
                 , name :: ByteString
                 , residue :: Int
                 , abbreviation :: ByteString
                 }
```

You can then do something like this:

```
a = Atom ...
a {residue=10} -- this is now a with a residue of 10
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did not realize that the record data structure allowed naming the individual components.  I am missing elementary stuff, here!

Comment: @kienjakenobi you should check out [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [other great resources](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Learning_Haskell).

Comment: Thanks, I have read portions of Lean You a Haskell, and I have even used records before.  I simply did not know that records had a naming scheme.